# Variable containing $(this) returns undefined after html has changed (only in IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem regarding jQuery. I was making pagination to work with ajax, so that user clicks on page number and that page loads in another div and displays on success. But I ran into a little problem.

I'm creating a new variable on pager link click which contains $(this) for future references. But the thing is that in success function I'm replacing pagers html with the new one using .html(). Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox but in IE(tested on 9 and 10) my variable returns 'undefined' after replacing pagers html.

Now I'm kind of lost, because shouldn't my variable still contain a reference to $(this), even after replacing pagers html? I don't know how to explain this better, so I hope someone understood my problem :)

Here's the code for link click

```
$('#pager').on('click', 'a', function(event){
event.preventDefault();

current_page = ($('#pager .current').index())+1;
var dis = $(this);

if(dis.parents('.pager-mid').length > 0) {
    var link_number = parseInt($(this).text());
}

if(dis.attr('href') != '#') {
    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url:dis.attr('href'),
        dis:dis,
        beforeSend:function(){
            $('<div class="text-center wait-remove"><div class="wait"></div></div>').insertBefore($('#pager'));
        },
        success:function(data){
            $('#pager').html($(data).find('#pager').html());
            $('.wait-remove').remove();
            var check_html = $(data).find('.galleries-page').html(),
                check_error = false;

            if(!check_error) {
                if(link_number) {
                    $('.galleries-page:eq('+(link_number-1)+')').html($(data).find('.galleries-page').html());
                } else {
                    if(dis.hasClass('next')) {
                        $('.galleries-page:eq('+(current_page)+')').html($(data).find('.galleries-page').html());
                    } else {
                        $('.galleries-page:eq('+(current_page-2)+')').html($(data).find('.galleries-page').html());
                    }
                }
            }



            if(dis.parents('.pager-mid').length > 0) {
                $('#galleries-inner').stop(true, false).animate({
                    'left':'-'+((link_number-1)*page_width)+'px'
                },600);
            } else {
                if(dis.hasClass('next')) {
                    $('#galleries-inner').stop(true, false).animate({
                        'left':'-'+((current_page)*page_width)+'px'
                    },600);
                } else {
                    $('#galleries-inner').stop(true, false).animate({
                        'left':'-'+((current_page-2)*page_width)+'px'
                    },600);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a known problem of IE caching ajax requests. Set the cache parameter.

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    // all your options/callbacks
});
```

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. I tried adding console.log(dis.parent().attr('class')) before and after this line $('#pager').html($(data).find('#pager').html());

First one returns 'page' and second returns 'undefined'